# Android Latest SDK Usage

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio suggests me to install Android SDK 8.0 (26 API), but should I **really** do it?
I believe that there are not so many devices with Android 8.0 (or even 7.0).

**So, my questions are:**

Should I always install(and use) latest Android SDK?

Won't there a problem with running my application on "lower" Androids?

Maybe I should simply use Android 6.0 SDK for now?

Thanks.

Comment: Always Use the latest sdk so that you app gets compiled (or rather has support) for all future devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you are developing your application, you will need to choose the platform version against which you will compile the application. In general, you should compile your application against the lowest possible version of the platform that your application can support.

also

> Android applications are generally forward-compatible with new versions of the Android platform.

To avoid problems running on lower versions you can set the minimum sdk version.

Adnroid documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html